# sql query for Q1&Q2?

Tags: mysql

Q1: Identify all candidates who are qualified for a position, and their positions
Q2: Identify all candidates who are qualified for a particular position, and the their position (i.e., no redundant skills)

```
create table JobSkills (
   job char(20),
   skill char(20),
   primary key(job, skill)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table Candidates (
   candidate char(20),
   skill char(20)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into JobSkills values
('DB Architect','SQL'),
('DB Architect','DB Design'),
('DB Architect','Python'),
('DB Architect','Team Player'),
('DB Architect','Passionate'),
('Front End Developer','JAVA'),
('Front End Developer','C#'),
('Front End Developer','Team Player'),
('Front End Developer','Passionate'),
('Office Manager','Passionate'),
('Office Manager','Office');

insert into Candidates values
('Ami', 'SQL'),
('Ami', 'DB Design'),
('Ami', 'Team Player'),
('Ami', 'Passionate'),
('Xi', 'SQL'),
('Xi', 'Python'),
('Xi', 'DB Design'),
('Xi', 'Team Player'),
('Xi', 'Passionate'),
('DJ', 'JAVA'),
('DJ', 'C#'),
('DJ', 'Team Player'),
('DJ', 'Passionate'),
('DJ', 'Python'),
('Steve', 'Passionate'),
('Steve', 'Leader'),
('Darrin', 'SQL'),
('Darrin', 'DB Design'),
('Darrin', 'C#'),
('Darrin', 'Python'),
('Darrin', 'JAVA'),
('Darrin', 'Office'),
('Darrin', 'Team Player'),
('Darrin', 'Leader'),
('Darrin', 'Passionate');
```

Comment: This is homework

Comment: questions i met in an interview,  unsolved...

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a candidate is "Qualified" when he/she has at least every skill that's expected of the job/position.

Then for the first question, I understand that a candidate can have more skills than the expected.

For that, a `GROUP` BY with a `HAVING` clause should do the trick.
The total skills of a job should be equal to the matching skills of a candidate.

```
-- Q1: Identify all candidates who are qualified for a position
--     and their positions
--
SELECT c.candidate, j.job AS position
FROM JobSkills AS j
JOIN Candidates AS c ON c.skill = j.skill
JOIN 
(
   SELECT job, COUNT(DISTINCT skill) AS TotalSkills 
   FROM JobSkills 
   GROUP BY job
) jobtot ON jobtot.job = j.job
GROUP BY c.candidate, j.job
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.skill) = MAX(jobtot.TotalSkills)
ORDER BY c.candidate, j.job, COUNT(DISTINCT c.skill) DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
candidate   job
---------   --------------------
Darrin      DB Architect
Darrin      Front End Developer
Darrin      Office Manager
DJ          Front End Developer
Xi          DB Architect
```

But for the second I understand it as that the candidate can't have any extra skills that are not required by the job.

Then it's a bit more complicated.
Because then also the total skills of the candidate have to brought in the mix.

```
-- Q2: Identify all candidates who are qualified for a particular position
--     and the their position (i.e., no redundant skills)
--
SELECT cj.candidate, cj.job AS position
FROM 
(
  SELECT c.candidate, j.job, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT c.skill) AS TotalMAtchingSkills 
  FROM Candidates c
  JOIN JobSkills j ON j.skill = c.skill
  GROUP BY c.candidate, j.job
) cj
JOIN
(
   SELECT candidate, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT skill) AS TotalSkills 
   FROM Candidates 
   GROUP BY candidate
) candtot ON candtot.candidate = cj.candidate 
         AND candtot.TotalSkills = cj.TotalMAtchingSkills
JOIN
(
   SELECT job, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT skill) AS TotalSkills 
   FROM JobSkills 
   GROUP BY job
) jobtot ON jobtot.job = cj.job
        AND jobtot.TotalSkills = cj.TotalMAtchingSkills
ORDER BY cj.candidate, cj.job;
```

**Result:**

```
candidate   job
----------  ------------
Xi          DB Architect
```